# Error When Opening URL's from a text file

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I am trying to make a program which opens an URL written in a text file. My program reads from the file and tries to open the url but gets the error

> TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike,
>   not list

I have tried `readlines()`, `readline()` as i wish to open the second url in the file.

Here is the code

```
import webbrowser as wb

r_file = open("Websites.txt","r")


url = r_file.readlines()



print(url)


wb.open(url, new=0)

r_file.close()
```

Comment: If it contains one url then `read()` is enough

Comment: You have to literate over urls returned from readlines.

Answer (score 0):

It's simplest to process lines in a file using a `with` statement (files are context managers in Python, meaning they are designed for use in `with` statements and the like):

```
open("Websites.txt","r") as in_file:
    for url in_file:
        wb.open(url.strip(), new=0)
        input("Next page: ")
```

I've taken the precaution of removing any whitespace from the start or end of the URL, and added an `input` call to give you chance to bring the URLs up one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

import webbrowser as wb

r_file = open("C:\Users\RichardSkeggs\OneDrive - Alchemmy\prj\Belron\data\Websites.txt","r")

url = r_file.readlines()

for line in url:
    print(line)
    line=line.strip('\n')
    wb.open(line, new=0)

r_file.close()

The first step is loop through the list of entries picked up from the text file.
You need to remove the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

.readlines returns a list but wb.open() waits a string
 you can use something like that to solve your problem

```
import webbrowser as wb

r_file = open("Websites.txt","r")

urls = r_file.readlines()
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    wb.open(url, new=0)
r_file.close()
```